# Error:- unfortunately app stopped - android studio ,, runtime fatal Exception

Tags: java, android-studio, runtimeexception

Whenever I run my application from Android Studio I get an error message

> unfortunately,  has stopped.

My code:

```
package com.example.codequiz;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView header,Quetion,Score_view;
    Button True_btn,false_btn,webbutton,email_btn;
    boolean inter;
    int total =0;
    int index = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        header = findViewById(R.id.header);
        Quetion = findViewById(R.id.Quetion);
        Score_view = findViewById(R.id.Score_view);
        True_btn = findViewById(R.id.True_btn);
        false_btn = findViewById(R.id.false_btn);
        webbutton = findViewById(R.id.webbutton);
        email_btn = findViewById(R.id.email_btn);

        String []qt_no = {"java is a object oriented programming.", "Java is the official language of android", "java is widely used by business", "java is made by Sachin", "java is best alternative of Kotlin" };
        Boolean []check = {true,true,true,false,true};

        Quetion.setText(qt_no[index]);

      True_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              inter= true;
              index++;
              Quetion.setText(qt_no[index]);

          }
      });

      false_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              inter = false;
              index++;
              Quetion.setText(qt_no[index]);
          }
      });

      if (inter==check[index]){
          total+=1;
      }

      Score_view.setText("Your Score is " +total);
    }
}
```

logcat error message

```
01-01 08:40:39.743 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat
01-01 08:40:39.743 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat
01-01 08:40:39.917 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
01-01 08:40:39.917 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
01-01 08:40:39.932 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
01-01 08:40:39.932 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
01-01 08:40:40.185 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
01-01 08:40:40.185 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
01-01 08:40:40.208 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
01-01 08:40:40.208 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
01-01 08:40:40.594 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextClassifierHelper.getTextClassifier
01-01 08:40:40.594 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextClassifierHelper.getTextClassifier
01-01 08:40:40.907 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.codequiz, PID: 508
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.codequiz/com.example.codequiz.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5055)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.codequiz.MainActivity.onCreate**(MainActivity.java:20)**
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5055) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070076
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:214)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:63)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:82)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.example.codequiz.MainActivity.onCreate***(MainActivity.java:20)*** 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5055) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-01 08:40:40.907 508-508/com.example.codequiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.codequiz, PID: 508
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.codequiz/com.example.codequiz.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5055)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.codequiz.MainActivity.onCreate**(MainActivity.java:20)**
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5055) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070076
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:214)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:63)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:82)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.example.codequiz.MainActivity.onCreate**(MainActivity.java:20)** 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5055) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    
    
    [ 01-01 08:40:40.987    50:   62 ?/u        ]
    
    
    [ 01-01 08:40:40.987    50:   62 ?/u        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert ***qt_no[index]*** to string type before passing it as an argument to *setText()* function.
This might be one of the reasons for the error *Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets'*.

You can refer to this documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets)

Comment: but my error is occurring due to line no 20. may you tell me what is the problem with this line.                                                                                                                             
    ==== setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    (this is line no. 20)

Comment: Error for this line could occur if the "activity_main" XML file has been modified or positioned somewhere in the project. Suppose it was not the reason, then try rebuilding your project.